# Angular.js + Karma + Jasmine: Unknown provider for service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I'm writing a test for the following Angular.js service:

```
var module = angular.module('wp', [ 'aws', 'lodash', 'jquery', 'moment', 'wp.model' ]);

/**
 * Wordpress service.
 */
module.service('wpService', function(_, $http, $q, $aws, Post) {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * HTTP request.
     */
    this.http = function(config) {
        var $config = _.clone(config);

        if ($config.user && $config.password) {
            $config.headers = $config.headers || {};
            $config.headers.Authorization = 'Basic ' + btoa($config.user + ':' + $config.password);
        }

        return $http($config);
    };

    // ..
}
```

The test case is as follows:

```
/**
 * Unit tests for wpService.
 */
describe('apService', function() {

    var wpService;

    beforeEach(angular.module('wp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_wpService_) {
        wpService = _wpService_;
    }));

    it('is defined', function() {
        expect(wpService).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

This looks to be about as text-book as it gets. Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
Chrome 43.0.2357 (Mac OS X 10.10.3) apService is defined FAILED
TypeError: queueableFn.fn.call is not a function
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: wpServiceProvider <- wpService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.1/$injector/unpr?p0=wpServiceProvider%20%3C-%20wpService
    at /Users/jdolan/Coding/tuuli-syndicate/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
```

My karma.config.js includes the modules as well as `angular-mocks.js`:

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files : [ 'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
              'bower_components/lodash/lodash.js',
              'bower_components/moment/moment.js',
              'bower_components/x2js/xml2json.js',
              'bower_components/aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk.js',
              'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
              'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
              'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
              'app/**/*.js',
              'tests/**/*.js' ],
```

I'm using Angular 1.4.1, Karma 0.12.36.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read [the angular-mocks example here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.inject) closely.

The `angular.module()` function returns an actual angular module, while `module()` is short for `angular.mock.module()`. Replace this line in your code and you should be all set:

```
beforeEach(module('wp'));
```

Comment: Good lord. Thank you.